# How to write my code in xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Is it possible to write this code below in the .xaml file instead of the .xaml.vb file?

```
Private Sub combx_Auswahl_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles combx_Auswahl.SelectionChanged
    If combx_Auswahl.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lbl_NeueMailAdresse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        txtbx_neueEmail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung.IsEnabled = True
        btn_AbbruchBearbeitung.IsEnabled = True
    Else
        lbl_NeueMailAdresse.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        txtbx_neueEmail.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung.IsEnabled = True
        btn_AbbruchBearbeitung.IsEnabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

My .xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_BackToMainWindow" Content="zurück" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="150" Margin="37,539,0,0" Height="23"/>
<Button x:Name="btn_AbbruchBearbeitung" Content="abbrechen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="150" Margin="205,460,0,0" Height="23"/>
<Button x:Name="btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung" Content="bestätigen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,460,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="150" Height="23"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="combx_Auswahl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318"/>
```

Comment: @mm8 added xaml, do need more? i cutted only the used lines

Comment: @Raizzen: you can do it, just that you'd need to use `Triggers`. MSDN has lots of examples on this, so I won't pollute the SO answers section with identical trivia on this.

Comment: @code4life ok iam sry. i dont know the right names i have to search for, i will try triggers

Comment: @Raizzen: See my answer.

Comment: @Raizzen: no worries, man. I wasn't being snarky, I just truly do hate posting exactly the same material all over SO. It usually proves to be counterproductive. Also, URL links tend to become dead links over the years, whereas Google is always a good friend in need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that all controls belong to the same namescope, you could use styles with a data trigger:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combx_Auswahl}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combx_Auswahl}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="combx_Auswahl">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Label x:Name="lbl_NeueMailAdresse" Style="{StaticResource style}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtbx_neueEmail" Style="{StaticResource style}" />
<Button Content="Button" x:Name="btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
```

Comment: i've commented my event and tried ur xaml changes, but nothing happens if i change the SelectedIndex of the combobox when i start the programm

Comment: Did you change "combx_Auswahl" to "combx_UnzustellbarMailAuswahl" or whatever your control is called? Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: no, iam sry i posted the wrong comboBox xaml code. Do i have to remove the Visibility="Hidden" in <Label> ? i just added the "Style="{..."

Comment: Yes. You can only set the Visibility property in the Style. See my sample markup.

Comment: ah i see! Now it works perfectly! but i have one question about ur code: <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="Control"> why control? and not Label or TextBox? if control stands for everything, why the extra style for the button

Comment: I only used a TargetType of Control to be able to use the same Style for the Label and the TextBox. You could use two different styles with two different target types if you wan to. It was just an example. And the button style sets the IsEnabled property rather than the Visibility property so this one is different.

Comment: Ah right iam sry. Just one more question.. the buttons shoulld be Enabled anytime if the SelectedIndex is not -1 (nothing) is there an operator like != or <> (not like) -1?

Comment: No, I am afraid there is no such operator available in XAML.

Comment: Huh.. sad. So i gonna keep the Button part in the Event in the Code :) Thx for the help - problem solved